# Why yarn cli does not list any container?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

let's consider a following scenario:

```
[user@host ~]$ yarn applicationattempt -list application_1620157095390_0392
Total number of application attempts :1
         ApplicationAttempt-Id                 State                        AM-Container-Id                        
appattempt_1620157095390_0392_000001                FINISHED    container_1620157095390_0392_01_000001
[user@host ~]$ yarn container -list appattempt_1620157095390_0392_000001
Total number of containers :0
                  Container-Id            Start Time             Finish Time                   State                    Host       Node Http Address                                LOG-URL
```

Could someone explain me why it does not show any container? I am sure that for this app some containers were executed.
My version of hadoop is `3`.

Comment: I think you meant to use `container_1620157095390_0392_01_000001`

Comment: Then, it returns null.